# How to access bearer token in Azure Data Factory through Link Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory

I am facing an issue in accessing the bearer token. I am using Authentication type ='OAuth2 Client Credential'.
And trying to fetch the details in REST API. I am passing the client ID and secret. But the connection is not set up.

Also, the bearer token expires in 1hr. So how that can be refreshed?

If someone can help would be very helpful.

Regards,[image]

Comment: Has anyone replied? Some thing wrong happened  bymistakenly from my end.

Answer (score 0):

To connect a REST API with `OAuth2 client credential` in Linked Service successfully, follow the procedure below:

Create [service principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/create-service-principal-azure) and
Add the required role to the user/service principal by following this procedure:

1. Go to API, then Access control, click on Add and select Add Role Assignment, as shown below:

[image]

2. select reader role, select the member, and add it. Afterward, go to the service principal, then the endpoint, and select `OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v1)` as shown below:

[image]

3. Copy the ClientID and Client Secret from the service principal and use them in the REST API Linked Service. Test the Linked Service, and it will be successful, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: #Bhavani Thank you for the response.
how can i access service principal, then the endpoint, and select OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v1). Can you please let me know?

Comment: @John I have updated my answer you can check there.